# Reveal header on pull and pin until scroll + pull to refresh

Tags: flutter, pull-to-refresh

I implemented the following header reveal on pull in Flutter but it does not work properly and I want to add more advanced features.

[image: test]

The subheader should stick to the top of the list once it is fully revealed. And it should get unpinned once the user scrolls it a bit back up.

My problem is that I also want to support the pull to refresh once the user pulls even more (the pull to refresh should be even above the subheader).

I tried the following, but it obviously does not work for many reasons:

- the subheader is not part of the scroll container and hence

  - the subheader does not stick to the items when wanting to do pull to refresh and
  - the user cannot "move it up to hide it again" unless scrolling on the list (but should be able to do the gesture on the subheader itself)
- Later I want to have a red dot in the `AppBar` that should become the subheader by animating it, which probably requires a `CustomScroll` approach together with some `CustomPainter` or so rather than my `Stack` + `ListView` stuff etc?

```dart
class RevealSubheaderPage extends HookWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    const double HEIGHT = 96;
    final pinned = useState(false);
    final extend = useState(0.0);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Test')),
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          NotificationListener<ScrollNotification>(
            onNotification: (n) {
              if (pinned.value) {
                print(n.metrics.pixels);
                if (n.metrics.pixels > 0 && n.metrics.pixels < HEIGHT) {
                  extend.value = n.metrics.pixels;
                }
              } else {
                if (n.metrics.pixels < 0) {
                  extend.value = n.metrics.pixels;
                }
                if (n.metrics.pixels < -HEIGHT) {
                  pinned.value = true;
                  extend.value = -HEIGHT;
                }
              }
              return false;
            },
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: 42,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Container(
                  color: Colors.green,
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
                  alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                  child: Text('Item $index'),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
          HideableWidget(height: HEIGHT, notifier: extend),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class HideableWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final double height;
  final ValueNotifier<double> notifier;

  HideableWidget({required this.height, required this.notifier});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ValueListenableBuilder<double>(
      valueListenable: notifier,
      builder: (context, value, child) {
        return Transform.translate(
          offset: Offset(0, -height - value),
          child: Container(
            height: height,
            width: double.infinity,
            color: Colors.red,
            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            child: Text("Subheader"),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

## Update

I was able to get it almost done using `CustomScrollView`, but as you can see I moved the revealed image in the vertical center. When I make it stick to the top/bottom I struggle with calculating the `BouncingScrollPhysics` offset so the widget would have a heigh of the total available space? By moving it to the middle it look ok-ish, but I would love to occupy the complete space. Also I was not able to integrate `RefreshIndicator` which should occure even above the subheader (so sould take another 100px of overscrolling before it starts being faded in).

[image: test]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_hooks/flutter_hooks.dart';

class Test3 extends StatelessWidget {

  const Test3({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: RevealSubheaderPage(
          revealHeight: 100,
          revealSnapHeight: 80,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class RevealSubheaderPage extends HookWidget {
  final double revealHeight;1
  final double revealSnapHeight;

  const RevealSubheaderPage({
    super.key,
    required this.revealHeight,
    required this.revealSnapHeight,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final snap = useState(false);
    final scrollExtend = useState(0.0);
    final scrollController = useScrollController();
    useEffect(() {
      l() {
        final o = scrollController.offset;
        scrollExtend.value = o;
        if (!snap.value && o < -revealSnapHeight) {
          snap.value = true;
        } else {
          if (snap.value && o > 0) {
            snap.value = false;
          }
        }
      }

      scrollController.addListener(l);
      return () => scrollController.removeListener(l);
    });

    return CustomScrollView(
      controller: scrollController,
      slivers: [
        const SliverAppBar(
          title: Text("Some Title"),
          pinned: true,
        ),
        SliverToBoxAdapter(
          child: Transform.translate(
            offset: Offset(
                0,
                snap.value
                    ? scrollExtend.value < 0
                        ? scrollExtend.value / 2
                        : 0
                    : scrollExtend.value < 0
                        ? scrollExtend.value / 2
                        : 0),
            child: AnimatedContainer(
              duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 150),
              height: snap.value
                  ? revealHeight
                  : scrollExtend.value < 0
                      ? -scrollExtend.value
                      : 0,
              child: Container(
                height: revealHeight,
                width: double.infinity,
                color: Colors.red,
                alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                child: Text("Subheader"),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        SliverList(
          delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
            childCount: 42,
            (context, index) {
              return Container(
                color: Colors.green,
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
                alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                child: Text('Item $index'),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```